# MySQL '=' operator not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database where I have an email field, among others.

When I do a SELECT statement like :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email = 'abcd@gmail.com';
```

...it returns an empty set, even though I can see the entry in the table.

The same statement works when I use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE fname = 'abcd';
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: did you run the query from phpmyadmin directly...?

Comment: Check there is no space before or after `abcd@gmail.com` in your db record.

Comment: answers already coming in thru. assumptions... :)

Comment: @Sudhir: That's fair enough when the question is "What could be going wrong?"

Comment: Is this a case-sensitivity issue? Perhaps the data is actually `'aBcD@gmail.com'`? Or otherwise an encoding issue, the data perhaps being `'abcd＠gmail.com'`? You can try like clauses to see where you start failing: `...LIKE 'a%'`, `...LIKE 'ab%'`, etc

Comment: Can you please paste the full, unabridged results of `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE fname = 'abcd';` so that we can provide an informed answer?

Answer (score 2):

use `trim` in your query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TRIM(`email`) = 'abcd@gmail.com';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90a95/3

Comment: But what if there is space in record in db ?

Comment: @Rikesh If space is present in db and user puts value without space than it will not give result. And this `trim` is used with db values and check with it.

Comment: But if this is the case, you might need to figure out why there is a space. This is like a temp solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some spaces in the entry that is stored in MySQL, Check if the stored email is exactly that without any blank space or unexpected character. You can also try the following to confirm this

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email LIKE '%abcd@gmail.com%'
```

Comment: Yes, I checked it both from command line, PHP query AND PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not have additional spaces? try  with `LIKE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email LIKE '%abcd@gmail.com%'
```

Comment: Tried this too. Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the entry contain extra spaces (tabs etc.) maybe?
You can try to:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email LIKE 'abcd@gmail.com%'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email LIKE '%abcd@gmail.com'
```

to see if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

use trim in the query .It will not consider spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check whether you are getting results for abcd@gmail.com or not.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE email LIKE '%abcd@%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work after a small but unintended change.

My old PHP query goes like this : 
    `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE email = '$email'");`

My new and changed query goes like this : 
    `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE email = ' $email'");`

For some reason, mysql_real_escape_string() was adding one extra space at the beginning, I think, which wasn't visible in PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score -1):

try below code. thinks it will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `email' = 'abcd@gmail.com';
```

Comment: "-" vote is ok. but plz give some comment. why is this negative?

Comment: What do you expect this query to do differently? (This is of course ignoring the fact that you have mismatched quotes)

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP's question? That is, what does this query do differently from that in the question?

Comment: I think I understand OP's question. So tried to give instruction for using `email' insted of email.

Comment: So you've tried their query and it didn't work, and doing this fixed it?

Comment: I got it to work after a small but unintended change.

My old PHP query goes like this : 
    `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE email = '$email'");`

My new and changed query goes like this : 
    `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE email = ' $email'");`

For some reason, mysql_real_escape_string() was adding one extra space at the beginning, I think, which wasn't visible in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly you can try trim($email) i.e. `email` = trim($email)